# Dynamically create methods in java

Tags: java

I have a csv file in this form :

DogType, DogName, DogColor
GermanShephred, Jim, brown

in the main class I created a dog object (from the dog class) such that

```
dog.setDogType = GermanShephred;
dog.SetDogName = Jim;
dog.SetDogColor = brown;
```

and then put it into a hashtable :

```
hashtable.put(dog,GermanShephred);
```

I need to generalise the code, which means that it is the user who decides the number of categories (DogType, DogName, DogColor, DogAge, DogSex) and the methods SetDogName, etc. should not be hardcoded in the dog class anymore because we don't know in advance how many categories there will be.

I don't know how to do that. Should I dynamically create methods in the dog class ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can't do what you want in `Java`, try `JavaScript`, `Python` or another language that supports such behavior.

Comment: BTW, You will want to use a HashMap instead of a Hashtable, unless you really have to.

Comment: don't use `Hashtable` in new code, it isn't 1996 anymore!

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you can hold all the animal's attributes in a map:

```
public class Dog
{
    final public Map<String,String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Then

```
final Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.attributes.put("type", "German Shepherd");
dog.attributes.put("name", "Jim");
dog.attributes.put("color", "Brown");
```

load whatever attributes the user provides into the map. when you need to output/display your dog, dump the map values.

Comment: I admit, I'm confused about the downvotes on this one. It was the first idea that popped in my head too. Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: This is the correct way to solve this problem.  There's no way that user-entered data should show up as method names or field names.

Comment: The only suggestion I might make is to change the generic types to `<String, Object>`, since attributes may not always be represented as strings (could be numbers, etc).

Comment: @PaulRichter the problem with that suggestion is that you can't tell, by reading the CSV file, what type a column ought to be.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ah yes this is true.

Comment: My only reservation here is about `attributes` being public.  I would prefer for it to be private, and give the `Dog` class methods `public void setAttribute(String name, String value)` and `public String getAttribute(String name)`.

Comment: `setXXX` and `getXXX` don't get you anything except more to type in this case, especially since the map is declared `final`.

Comment: I'd prefer for my `Dog` to have a cleaner API, so that I have less to change in the future if I decide on a different structure for my attributes.  @JarrodRoberson